# MongoDB Update GridFS Record

Tags: php, mongodb, file-upload, gridfs

I have implemented `CRUD` operations using `PHP + MongoDB`. The below code is used to upload any file using `GridFS`.

```
$conn = new MongoClient();
            $db = $conn->selectDB('mydb');
            $gridfs = $db->getGridFS('uploads');

            foreach ($_FILES as $file) {

                if(in_array($file['type'], $acceptedTypes)){    

                $id = $gridfs->storeFile($file['tmp_name'], array('filename' => $file['name'], 'type' => $file['type'], "id"=> 13, "parentId" => "10", "title" => $file['name'], "isFolder" => 0));


                }else{

                    echo 'file is not of correct type';
                }
            }
    $conn->close();`
```

I am able to upload any document using above code, but when I try to update the `title` of any file it just do not work. The code to update the file name is as below.

```
$files = $db->fs->uploads;
$primId = $_GET['id_value'];
$renameTitle = $_GET['name'];
$updateData = array("title" => $renameTitle, "updatedDate" => date('Y-m-d'));

$files->update(array("id" => $primId), array( '$set' => $updateData ));
$conn->close();
```

This will update the `title` of any file whose `ID` is passed. The code works if I need to update any record but its not working for any `GridFS` file upload.

To be more precise if I pass `ID` like below,

```
$file = $gridfs->findOne(array('id' => 13)); **//WORKS**

$file = $gridfs->findOne(array('id' => $_GET['id'])); **//DO NOT WORKS**
```

Is there any other method to be used in order to update `GridFS` records ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

MongoDB needs `integer` variable to create the right query.

If you are using `$_GET` or `$_POST` values directly, you should first convert it to integer value. In my project it works like this :

```
$id = (int)$_GET["id"]; 
$file = $gridfs->findOne(array('id' => $id)); **//WORKS LIKE CHARM**
```

Hope it helps someone.